# How to parse nested json in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I am new to rails. I am trying to consume json in rails. I am not able to consume nested json in rails

Json format is

```
{
"userId": "String",
"firstName": "String",
"role": [{
    "createdTime": 1469361928825,
    "updatedTime": 1469361928825,
    "createdBy": "String",
    "id": "String",
    "role": "String",
    "explanation": "String",
    "locationId": "String",
    "hospitalId": "String",
    "accessModules": [{
        "module": "String",
        "url": "String",
        "accessPermissions": [{
            "accessPermissionType": "READ",
            "accessPermissionValue": false
        }]
    }, {
        "module": "String",
        "url": "String",
        "accessPermissions": [{
            "accessPermissionType": "WRITE",
            "accessPermissionValue": false
        }]
    }, {
        "module": "CONTACT",
        "url": "CONTACT",
        "accessPermissions": [{
            "accessPermissionType": "HIDE",
            "accessPermissionValue": false
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "createdTime": 1469361928831,
    "updatedTime": 1469361928831,
    "createdBy": "String",
    "id": "String",
    "role": "String",
    "explanation": "String",
    "locationId": "String",
    "hospitalId": "String",
    "accessModules": [{
        "module": "String",
        "url": "String",
        "accessPermissions": [{
            "accessPermissionType": "READ",
            "accessPermissionValue": false
        }]
    }, {
        "module": "String",
        "url": "String",
        "accessPermissions": [{
            "accessPermissionType": "WRITE",
            "accessPermissionValue": false
        }]
    }, {
        "module": "CONTACT",
        "url": "CONTACT",
        "accessPermissions": [{
            "accessPermissionType": "HIDE",
            "accessPermissionValue": false
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "createdTime": 1469361928837,
    "updatedTime": 1469361928837,
    "createdBy": "String",
    "id": "String",
    "role": "String",
    "explanation": "String",
    "locationId": "String",
    "hospitalId": "String",
    "accessModules": [{
        "module": "String",
        "url": "String",
        "accessPermissions": [{
            "accessPermissionType": "READ",
            "accessPermissionValue": false
        }]
    }, {
        "module": "String",
        "url": "String",
        "accessPermissions": [{
            "accessPermissionType": "WRITE",
            "accessPermissionValue": false
        }]
    }, {
        "module": "CONTACT",
        "url": "CONTACT",
        "accessPermissions": [{
            "accessPermissionType": "HIDE",
            "accessPermissionValue": false
        }]
    }]
}],
"isActivate": true,
"lastSession": 1471069942314,
"discarded": false
```

}

Rails code is as follows -

```
response[:data].each do |obj|
      users << {
        first_name: obj[:firstName],
        user_id: obj[:userId],
        role_id: obj[:role][:id],
        role: obj[:role][:role],
        role_type: obj[:role][:accessModules][:accessPermissions][:accessPermissionType],
      } unless obj[:discarded]
    end
    render json: {success: true, users: users}
  end
```

While consuming JSON I am not able to parse it properly. I

Comment: Is something in your JSON example missing? I see no `data`. `obj[:role][:id]` seems missing an id. Within your JSON document its an array of hashes. I would expect some thing like `obj[:role][0][:id]`

Comment: There is no attribute `data``in your JSON. You are also accessing `obj[:role][:accessModules]` which is array. You have to do something like `obj[:role][:accessModules].first[:accessPermissions] ...`